# Why is this program only displaying one hyphen even when the parameter is set to 5, for example

Tags: java, loops

for these guidelines:

Write the definition of a method  dashedLine , with one parameter, an  int .

If the parameter is negative or zero, the method does nothing. Otherwise it prints a complete line terminated by a newline to standard output consisting of dashes (hyphens) with the parameter's value determining the number of dashes. The method returns nothing.

I wrote the following code, but it only prints one hyphen when I run in eclipse and give it a test parameter of 5. I'm thinking I may need to use a for loop instead. I think it loops within the loop therefor only giving one hyphen back.

how can I 'remedy' this code?

```
void dashedLine(int x)
    {
        int i=0;
        if(x>0) 
            {
            if(i<=x)
                {
                    i++;
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
                else
                    System.out.print("\n");

            }
    }
```

Comment: would
for(i=0; i<x ; i++)
work better?

Comment: thanks! I tried both this and the answer below. both worked fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But there is no loop. `if` is not a loop. `for` `while` and `do while` are the three different loops in Java. You should rather have:

```
void dashedLine(int x)
{
    for (int i=0;i<x;i++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: I used the first solution proposed, just because It's something Iv'e never seen before, but this is the approach I was asked to use.
thank you for clearing up that IF is not a loop!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a loop here: `while`, `for`, `do-while` instead of a conditional `if`.

```
while(i++ <= x) {
  System.out.print("-");
}
```

Comment: Oh cool! I didn't even know it could be done that way!
does the while loop go through its functions and then modify its parenthesis content? Or does the (i++ <= x) mean go through commands and every loop add to i without referring to parenthesis content? 
...Does that make any sense? lol

Comment: TL;DR I've never seen the left side of the Boolean have a ++ attached to it. A short explanation would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

As you proposed, you should use FOR loop here:

```
  for ( i = 0; i < x; i++ )
  {
    System.out.print("-");
  }
  System.out.print("\n");
```